# intellij 15 idea new a jsp file in spring boot project

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I use intellij idea to develop a spring boot project, when i want to new a `.jsp` file, I can not find where is the `.jsp` option in the menu, and my mean screen shot is following:

[menu screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGQiH.jpg)

I know pick `File` and type the name of the file with a `.jsp` extension. but I think it is not a appropriate way, because we never create a file with `.java` suffix for example by this way.

Answer (score 0):

Just pick File and type the name of the file with a .jsp extension.

Comment: Sorry I didn't describe my question properly, and now I revise my question, thank you all the same.

Comment: My answer is still correct.  IntelliJ does not include a specific menu item for every possible type of template engine.  Java files are part of a language but templates can be implemented by anyone.